# Need to convert random output to string

Tags: python

I`m trying to make a hangman game, and I'm having some trouble.

```
import random

list_words = ["cataaaaaaaaaa", "hat", "computer", "thursday", "idiot", "catnip", "sunday"]

name = (random.sample(list_words, 1)[0])
print(f"The word is {len(name)} characters long.")

var_under = ("_" * len(name))
```

I'm looking for a way to turn var_under into a string with fixed length, so I can manipulate it further. It's supposed to be the empty spaces the letters replace in the game.

Sorry if this is very easy, I'm trying to learn on my own.

Comment: `var_under` *is* a string a string in your code. You also might consider `name = random.choice(list_words)`.

Comment: It doesn't seem very clear what you are having trouble in?

Comment: I`m sorry, I dont think i managed to convey what my problem is. My code gives me a  _ for each letter in the random word. But I need to convert it to a string or something that i can then replace the  _  with correctly guessed letters, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

One possible way may be to use `var_under` as `list` and change the values accordingly. Something like below:

```
# before assignment character
var_under = ["_"] * len(name)
print(' '.join(var_under)) # outputs: _ _ _ _ _ _

# after assignment
var_under[1] = 'a' # user entered value assigned to index
print(' '.join(var_under)) # outputs: _ a _ _ _ _
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That did the trick. Guess I need to read about the join command.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the str() method to `var_under`.

I modified the code below and var_under is now an `str` type after modification.

```
import random

list_words = ["cataaaaaaaaaa", "hat", "computer", "thursday", "idiot", "catnip", "sunday"]

name = (random.sample(list_words, 1)[0])
print(f"The word is {len(name)} characters long.")

var_under = str("_" * len(name))

print(var_under)
print(type(var_under))
```